# Click event on jTable -Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, listeners

I have created a table in java in Netbeans and filled it with some data. Now I want to show some detail in a text area corresponding to the particular column in a row when I click on that cell. How can I find out using event listener that on which cell user has clicked.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Find the location of the click event and get the cell you are searching for:

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int col = jTable1.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
            ......

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Whoa! Such an elegant answer! I've tried to add a MouseListener to overide item selection event but it didn't work, turn out I have to use MouseAdapter. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

[JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) can listnening for selected TableCell (by mouseclick or from keyboard),you have to look for implemets [ListSelectionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html), examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262099/jtable-change-cell-background-at-mouse-click-after-release-change-background-ba/7262163#7262163) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900628/refreshing-background-color-for-a-row-in-jtable/6901508#6901508)