# How to get the table whose cell is currently being clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've two tables in panels. When I click on first table on some cell, its row is getting selected. And when I click on the second table on some cell, its row is also getting selected.

Now, How will I come to know, which table is last clicked. I tried with `isRowSelected` on both the tables, both are returning, so I'm not able to find the last clicked table?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: some code will be helpful, have you tried with click events?

Answer (score 2):

you have to read how

- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)
- [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

works,

you have to understand both concepts, simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262099/jtable-change-cell-background-at-mouse-click-after-release-change-background-b/7262163#7262163), another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this must be determined from a MouseListener or from a ListSelectionListener, but the simplest solution is similar: use a different listener for each table:

```
table1.addXxxListener(new XxxListener() {
    // here, you know it's table 1
}


table2.addXxxListener(new XxxListener() {
    // here, you know it's table 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to check the source of the event:

```
new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==table1.getSelectionModel()) {
             // Event comes from table1
        } else if (e.getSource()==table2.getSelectionModel()) {
             // Event comes from table2
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is true if and only if the selection model is used by a single table (which is the case if you have not set your own ListSelectionModel)